# Right most visible position/character of a QListWidgetItem?

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget

I have a `QListWidget`, in which I have added few `QListWidgetItem`s with some text.
Some of these items have to have right pointing triangle (using unicode) at the right most visible position.

Is there any way that I can calculate position of right most visible character so that I can insert white space between and then right poiting triangle?

It would be great if there is a dynamic way to know this information. 
Cause this list is not static, it changes as per change in a combobox... So sometimes there may be scroll bar, sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
ui->listWidget->addItem(("▶ text"));
QString st = ui->listWidget->item(0)->text();//just get text from item
int pos = st.indexOf("▶");//find position
if(pos == -1)
    qDebug() << "this iten doesn't have this symbol";
//st.insert(pos,"A");//now you have position, you can insert what you want
ui->listWidget->item(0)->setText(st);//set text back to the item
```

It is example, so maybe you need adapt this code to your.

To do this dynamically, you can use signals/slots mechanism. `QComboBox` has great signal : `currentIndexChanged ( const QString & text )`